# Tkinter Label Won't Update

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a program that is similar to cookie clicker, and the "Hireprice" label won't update. Here is my code. I don't understand why the label is not working,and any suggestions would help.

```
from Tkinter import *
Cookies = 0
Helpers = 1
HirePrice = 100
CCK = Tk()
CCK.geometry("200x200")
CCK.title("Cookie Clicker")
CCookies = IntVar()
CCookies.set(Cookies)
def Bake():
    global Cookies
    global Helpers
    Cookies = Cookies + Helpers
    CCookies.set(Cookies)
def HelperHire():
    global Helpers
    global HirePrice
    global CCookies
    global Cookies
    global HireLabel
    global HireLabelTk
    if Cookies >= HirePrice:
        Helpers = Helpers + 1
        Cookies = Cookies - HirePrice
        CCookies.set(Cookies)
        HirePrice = HirePrice * 2.5
        HireLabel = "Hire Price: " + str(HirePrice)
        HireLabelTk = StringVar()
        HireLabelTk.set(HireLabel)
HireLabel = "Hire Price: " + str(HirePrice)
HireLabelTk = StringVar()
HireLabelTk.set(HireLabel)
Hireprice = Label(CCK,textvariable = HireLabelTk, padx = 20,pady = 10)
Hireprice.pack()
BakeButton = Button(CCK,text = "Bake!", padx = 15, pady = 1, width = 10, height = 1, command = Bake)
BakeButton.pack()
HireButton = Button(CCK,text = "Hire a helper!", padx = 15, pady = 1, width = 10, height = 1, command = HelperHire)
HireButton.pack()
CookieNum = Label(CCK,textvariable = CCookies, padx = 10,pady = 100)
CookieNum.pack()
CCK.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably because you wrote `Hireprice` instead of `HirePrice`

Comment: Oh wait! it didnt work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you change the value, you create a new instance of `StringVar` rather than updating the one associated with the label. Remove `HireLabelTk = StringVar()` from `HelperHire`.